# Internal drives partitions are not showing!

Tags: partitioning, automount, filemanager

I'm using Sony-Vaio netbook with 2GB ram and 250GB hdd. I've installed UBUNTU 14.04 LTS which I'm enjoying very much. I've 4 partitions as under:

```
/dev/sda1 >> 30GB >> Linux 
/dev/sda2>> 10GB>> HPFS/NTFS/exFAT (Windows XP installed)
[/dev/sda3 Extended]
/dev/sda5>> 86GB>> W95 FAT32
/dev/sda6>> 124GB>> W95 FAT32
```

sda1 and sda2 are ok as they are meant to be.

Problems are with sda5 and sda6. These two partitions are mounted (as per 'Disks' app) and are exist in the folder '/mnt'. They are accessible- can browse there contents. But neither they are appearing as a drive in the left panel of the nautilus file manager under 'Device' category nor in the side bar on the desktop!

My `fstab` file entries are (all):

```
UUID=b3cd2da1-a745-4cd3-98f7  / ext4  errors=remount-ro    0  1  

/dev/sda2  /mnt/sda2    auto  nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto   0  0  

LABEL=MyEnt  /mnt/MyEnt   auto  defaults,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000   0  0  
LABEL=MyBkp  /mnt/MyBkp   auto  defaults,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000   0  0
```

Can anyone please help me to make these two drives visible?

Answer (score 2):

The gui only shows partitions that are mounted under /media/.  Since you have them mounted under /mnt, they are not shown.  Either manually change the fstab entries to mount them under /media, or remove the entries entirely and let the system automatically mount them there.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have them mounted using fstab. If you want them to show up on the left hand side of nautilus, comment out or delete those lines from `/etc/fstab` and reboot.

After you reboot, the partitions should appear on the left hand side and will be available under `/media/<username>` **after** you click on each partition to mount it.